# backand platform: how debug server platform code localy

Tags: backand

The [documantion mention](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/customactions/index.html#server-side-node-js-code) that there is a way to develop entire project localy and then upload it to back& platform for production. how can it be done?

There is sample code somewhere ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The server side in Back& can be built with cloud JavaScript or with node.js.
Using Backand CLI and node.js you can develop any project in node.js and upload it.
The steps are simple:

1. Create new action with "Server side node.js code"
2. Run the action.init command (copy paste from the action page)
3. Use the backand shell project to build the node.js project
4. Run action.deploy command to upload and run the code on the server

Comment: 1. "server side node.js code" is the  Back& site ??
2. "copy paste from the action page"

Comment: @perymimon yes in Back& site, under Actions tab, create new Action (then select server side node.js type)

Comment: ok that clear but. 
2.`Run the action.init` where, on the command line of the client root project ? "copy paste from the action page" which page. on the back& site GUI  ? what to copy from there ? the JS code or there is some CLI command there ?
3 & 4,can you reference inside the aswer to the `Github` project or provide some sample code ?

Comment: I do the steps instraction . but it take me until the point of `test CRUD` but I'm not sure that test give me the global object that exist in backand platform like 'socket, files, request, etc.. `

Answer (score 0):

for debug node.js localy :

first make sure you have `action` defind in the back& site under the section `objects/[objectName]/action`

example:

project name: `MyApp`
with object call: `Users` 
with the action `files` (for upload a images file)
so

In **local terminal**
  1. go to project's root folder.
  2. type `backand login` and follow the instraction (email & password).
  3. type `backand action init` and follow the instration.

> ```
> project name : MyApp,  
> object name : Users,  
> action name : files
> ```

to be continue...